# XML / Javascript to detect browser version 

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cross-browser

I have created an XML file and I was trying to access it using my web browser. 
When I used IE, the script worked really well and everything was OK but when I tried to open it in another browsers it didn't work.
After researches I learned that it's from the ActiveX content that I instance in the first line of my JavaScript that connects with Microsoft.
That's why I found another code that should automatically check the nature of the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "emp.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    //function loadXML(xmlFile)
    //{
    //xmlDoc.async="false";
    //xmlDoc.onreadystatechange=verify;
    //xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
    //xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    //}
```

Actually, just the last two lines of the function are enough to load the XML file. The previous two lines are written to ensure that the JavaScript functions that we may use later to manipulate the XML file data, does not perform any function on an uninitialized object. Thus the function **verify()**is called.

```
<?php
//function verify()/   
    //{
      // 0 Object is not initialized
      // 1 Loading object is loading data
      // 2 Loaded object has loaded data
      // 3 Data from object can be worked with
      // 4 Object completely initialized
      //if (xmlDoc.readyState != 4)
    //  {
        // return false;
      //}
    //}
?>

loadXML('emp.xml');
alert(xmlDoc.childNodes(0).firstChild.text);
alert(xmlDoc.childNodes(3).childNodes(1).firstChild.text);
```

I get JScript runtime error access is denied... what to do?

**MY NEW CODE:**

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.multimediaprof.com/test/emp.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
alert(xmlDoc.childNodes[1].firstChild.text);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Is `JQUERY` the answer, how do I implement it?

Comment: I guess you have taken things from different links if I'm not mistaken. Please read these links : <http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript> <http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/xml_javascript/xml_javascript.asp. Please follow one tutorial at a time. If you follow the tutorial you won't get any errors.

Comment: The second link u gave me is the one i started with, and it don't work on any browser other than IE, that's why i tried to put together two different links to try and make it work on any browser, even if i try the link with the testing function included, the JS runtime error occurs and it won't function on any browser...Any thoughts?

Comment: Here you have a very simple example, http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp. Remember, how to load files locally. Please verify the path the of the file 'xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");' you can give something like this 'File://C:/text.xml'

Comment: Try this http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html

Comment: I Tried to put the location of the xml online on my server, the error disappeared! but another one appeared !

Comment: The new one is that he can't find the childenodes , note that before putting the browser testing function, on IE i was capable of seeing the result in the alert , any thoughts plz

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to access a file on your computer through the `file://` protocol. This is a security risk and most browsers don't allow it.

A solution to this problem is to host your files on a server, local or online.

If you're using Google Chrome you could run it with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to make it work.

EDIT: I think you have a syntax error here:

```
alert(xmlDoc.childNodes(0).firstChild.text);
```

The `childNodes` object is an array, not a function. Thus, square brackets,`[]`, should be used, not parentheses, `()`.

EDIT2: If you're using jQuery, the syntax is as follows:

```
$.get("file.xml", function(data){
    //Your data is accessible through the data variable here!
    console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Further documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Your solution made the access error disappear, but there's a new error, The new one is that he can't find the childenodes , note that before putting the browser testing function, on IE i was capable of seeing the result in the alert , any thoughts plz

Comment: My bad, it worked.. can u just share some more knowledge about accessing local xml files? i'm very new at it

Comment: NB it didn't work on any browser besides the IE...what to do?

Comment: In any other browser, the document is considered null.
I did fix the syntax error i had, and the errors have the same concept : it is considered a null object

Comment: xmlDoc is considered Null in any other browser... What to do?

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery? Or is there some reason for you to do it natively?

Comment: @ELias Rahme: Please edit the question & put your entire code there.

Comment: If it could be solved using Jquery i will be glad to! But i need a bit help with the syntax i'm totally new...So i am going to edit my question and put my whole code in there and if there is anything i could do plz tell me

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else // for older IE 5/6
            {
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "/Users/kart2006/Desktop/emp.xml", false);
            xhttp.send("");
            xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

            document.write(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName + " loaded");
            var str = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            alert(str);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>

    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Remember, I have loaded the 'emp.xml' file in Mac. In windows ' File://'

[image][image]

Comment: your code worked perfectly on IE but just didn't workout on chrome neither firefox ... What to do??

Comment: @ELias Rahme: I have tested successfully in Firefox, Safari browsers.

Comment: For google chrome check here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=988

Comment: In firefox it still gives me that the xml document is null.. And in safari it just gets stuck in the middle of loading and nothing happens./..is there anthg i can do to make XML load from all browsers not only IE?

Comment: If it is 'null' then there is a problem in loading the XML file. Please check the path location of the file. Please check the screenshot of FF & Safari.

Comment: Still doesn't work :S the document is null ! i don't understand why is there anthg wrong!?

Comment: @ELias Rahme: Please show us, how do you locate the path of the file.